# Azure and SignalR: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, websocket, signalr

I'm currently experiencing this issue at a high frequency:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Sometimes it happens when connecting to Azure Storage from my web app (code below), but most of the time it happens with SignalR.

Based on debug diag, I see the following:

> 394 client connections in w3p.dmp have been executing a request for more than 90 seconds.

Based on the memory dump, there are a significant number of connections being made to `/signalr/connect` and `/signalr/reconnect`.

It looks like I'm using AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler to make SignalR connections from within code.  At this point I'm not sure what to look for though - what could be the culprit?  We have a web service living in Azure, with web apps and mobile apps connecting to a SignalR backplane (redis).

**Screen from debug diag**

[image]

**Code for Azure Storage**

```
    public void EnqueueRequest(int requestId)
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AzureStorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("requestQueueName"));

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(castingCallId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        queue.AddMessage(message);
    }
```

**Hub Proxy Code**

```
var baseUrl = _dbContext.CurrentTenant.BaseUrl;
_hubConnection = new HubConnection(baseUrl);
_hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("appHub");
await _hubConnection.Start();
string serialized = null;
try
{
   serialized = JsonSerializerExtensions.SerializeObject(data).SanitizeData();
   await _hubProxy.Invoke((isTypingNotification ? "SendTypingNotification" : "SendClientNotification"), serialized, username);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    LogError("1: " + exception);
}
```

Comment: The code snippet that you provided is used to operate Azure storage queue, which would not establish connection to hub server. Besides, as you said, it seems that lots of reconnect requests are sent from clients, please try to [enable SignalR tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#enabling-tracing-on-the-server)  to check if it could provide useful diagnostic information. And what are the version of SignalR and jQuery you are using now?

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT thanks - I'm aware that the code snippet doesn't use signalR at all, but it does break when connections are exhausted in the same manner.  I'll look into tracing now.

Comment: I have had a similar problem with the same exception. My issue turned out to be an improper use of a SignalR hub proxy. I also believe I was missing an await call. It was the devil to run that issue down. Can you post your code where you're connecting to your SignalR Hub?

Comment: @RobReagan this has been wreaking havoc on our app for the past couple days.  Can I pay you to help me track this down?

Comment: @SB2055, how about I just eyeball your code for free to start with? I can probably tell you quickly if it's the same issue that was responsible for at least half my hair loss. My email is rob@textrequest.com.

Comment: Does your _dbContext dispose your hub or does your hub dispose _dbContext? I am very curious about signalR and hope my comment helps!

Comment: I had a similar problem that turned out to be a hacker 'almost' ddos-ing ANOTHER app hosted on the same Azure plan. This other app happened to be using a weak library for connection to MySQL, and resulted in a lot of ports being left in WAIT states. The problem with that is that the remaining App Services on the Plan were then affected by plan-wide port exhaustion. Check your pricing tier and look for port exhaustion. http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ You have many open connections(for some reason)-may be a port limit you are hitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SB2055 and I worked on this and made the following changes to eliminate this issue:

1. Do not create a HubConnection for each message to send. A HubConnection is a heavyweight object and should be created once and reused. You can recreate the IHubProxy multiple times if needed. You can accomplish this by setting the HubConnection as a class static member variable.
2. We changed the connection type from web sockets to long polling.